# Why should the derivative of a parametrization to a manifold be one to one?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

Hubbard and Hubbard define the parameterization of a manifold $M \subset \Re^n$ as a mapping $\gamma : U \subset \Re^k \to M$ satisfying

1. $U$ is open
2. $\gamma$ is $C^1$, one to one and onto $M$
3. $D\gamma(\vec{u})$ is one to one for every $\vec{u} \in U$

Why is condition 3. required?

The only explanation I see in the textbook is that the columns of the derivative matrix should be linearly independent, but am unable to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your definition correctly, the tangent space $T_{u}M$ at $u \in U$ is induced by the chart $\gamma(\cdot)$ and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Thus, the one-to-one correspondence. But I have to say, this is the first time I see such kind of explicit requirement placed along with the definition(it is more like a consequence of the requirement for the chart to be invertible and smooth)